# Most efficient way to match 2d coordinates in Python

Tags: python

I have 3 lists of 2d arrays of non-negative integers, e.g.

```
l1 = [(1, 7), (0, 55), (13, 3), (100, 100)]
l2 = [(5, 3), (40, 50), (11, 99), (555, 666)]
l3 = [(0, 40), (100, 555), (111, 999)]
```

They are not all of the same length, and I know nothing about the distribution of these points other than that all values are in some range [0, N] (N is not too big, 2500-3000-ish).

I'm looking for an efficient way to match point from `l1` and `l2` based on couples in `l3`:
if there is a pair in `l3` such that the 1st coordinate is also a 1st coordinate in one of the pairs in `l1` AND the 2nd coordinate (in `l3` pair) is a 1st coordinate in a `l2` pair - than the 3 pairs "match".

For example, from the lists above we'll get

```
matches = [[(0,55), (40,50), (0,40)], [(100,100), (555,666), (100, 555)]]
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
l1_left_coordinates = [p[0] for p in l1]
l2_left_coordinates = [p[0] for p in l2]
for p in l3:
  left, right = p
  try:
    idx_of_left_in_l1 = l1_left_coordinates.index(left)
    idx_of_right_in_l2 = l2_left_coordinates.index(right)
  except ValueError:
    continue
  matches.append([l1[idx_of_left_in_l1], l2[idx_of_right_in_l2], p])
```

This works. But it means that for **every** `l3` element I traverse both `l1` and `l2`, resulting in `O(n^2)` worse-case runtime (where `n` is the size of the arrays). I wonder if there's a faster way to do this.

Comment: you could try creating a dict from l1 with the 1st coordinate as keys and as values a list of the points with that 1st coordinates, then do the same for l2 just using the 2nd coordinate as key. This way for each point in l3 you just need to check the subset of points in l1 and l2 that have the correct coordinate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting the list first, and only looking on the residual of the list will lead to a performance that could be approached with `O(nlog(n))` here's an example,
However the difference could not be noticed for small lists

```py
import time

l1 = [(1, 7), (0, 55), (13, 3), (100, 100)]
l2 = [(5, 3), (40, 50), (11, 99), (555, 666)]
l3 = [(0, 40), (100, 555), (111, 999)]

# l1 = [(random.randint(0,1000),random.randint(0,1000)) for _ in range(3000)]
# l2 = [(random.randint(0,1000),random.randint(0,1000)) for _ in range(3000)]
# l3 = [(random.randint(0,1000),random.randint(0,1000)) for _ in range(3000)]

start = time.time()
l1 = sorted(l1,key=lambda item : item[0])     # O(nlog(n))
l2 = sorted(l2,key=lambda item : item[0])     # O(nlog(n))
l3 = sorted(l3,key=lambda item : item[0])     # O(nlog(n))

matches = []
l1_left_coordinates = [p[0] for p in l1]   # O(n)
l2_left_coordinates = [p[0] for p in l2]   # O(n)

l1_idx = 0
l2_idx = 0 

l1_id_inc = 0
l2_id_inc = 0

for x,y in l3:  
    try: 
        l1_idx = l1_left_coordinates.index(x) # (log(n)) cause we only search on the residual of the list at each iteration of the wrapping loop.
        l2_idx = l2_left_coordinates.index(y)
        
        l1_id_inc += l1_idx
        l2_id_inc += l2_idx

        l1_left_coordinates = l1_left_coordinates[l1_idx:]  # slicing the residual
        l2_left_coordinates = l2_left_coordinates[l2_idx:]
    except ValueError:
        continue

    matches.append([l1[l1_id_inc], l2[l2_id_inc], (x,y)])

elapsed = time.time()-start
print(f"took :{elapsed} seconds to run")
print(matches)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you sort the lists l1 and l2 (n log n), and look for the p[0] in l1, p[1] in l2 by dichotomy (log n), it should be theorically better.
However, I am not sure how fast .index() is, so maybe your solution is already fast enough